# Cannot seem to be drop null valued rows from dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying the basic Titanic competition on Kaggle and am facing the issue of not being able to drop NaN valued rows. I wanted to check what was the rate of survival for everyone for whom age is listed in fractions (data mentions this case is for when age has been estimated)

```
estimated_age = train_data.loc[train_data.Age % 1 != 0]
estimated_age.dropna(axis = 1, how='any')
estimated_age[~estimated_age['Age'].isnull()]
```

[image: estimated_age.head()]

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, but as far as I've read, ideally it should drop the rows which contain NaN for Age.

Comment: in this line `estimated_age.dropna(axis = 1, how='any')` you aren't assigning back changes either assign back i.e `estimated_age=estimated_age.dropna(axis = 1, how='any')` or pass `inplace=True`

Comment: Aah, I see. And if I try this: `estimated_age = train_data.loc[train_data.Age % 1 != 0 & train_data.Age.notnull()]`? @AnuragDabas

Answer (score 2):

```
estimated_age.dropna(axis = 1, how='any')
```

should be

```
estimated_age.dropna(axis = 0, inplace=True, how='any')
```

If you want to drop **rows** including NaN values.

Comment: Thank you, could you also help me with this? `estimated_age = train_data.loc[train_data.Age % 1 != 0 & train_data.Age.notnull()]` I don't understand why this shouldn't work.

Comment: `train_data.Age % 1 != 0` seems interesting. It will be false for integers since all integers have 0 remainder when they divided by 1. The condition will be true only for non-integer numbers. Age values are probably integers. What were you planning to do with that condition?

Comment: One of the docs mentioned that if the age has been estimated, it would be mentioned in fraction i.e. if age estimated is 46, it would be mentioned as 46.5. So, I was trying to filter out integers and not null numbers. It successfully filtered out integers, but the NaN entries were still part of the estimated_age.

Answer (score 1):

in the `dropna`  part, you should add `inplace =True`

Comment: Thank you, could you also help me with this? `estimated_age = train_data.loc[train_data.Age % 1 != 0 & train_data.Age.notnull()]` I don't understand why this shouldn't work.

Comment: shouldn't work as in it crashes or it doesn't give you what you expect.